# Input type tel causing issue in iPhone

Tags: iphone, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, braintree

I am using ** PayPal Powered by Braintree for WooCommerce** woocommerce plugin extension for Card Payment.

But i recently found that fields under card payment have input type as **tel** and this is not allowing me to add symbol slash (/) in **Expiration Date** field specially in iPhone.

Is there any chance to overcome this issue in iPhone?

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ez12xq

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

There are two ways to work around this issue:

1. Update your `placeholder` to `MMYY` (you could do this dynamically based on browser)
2. Break your `expirationDate` into two separate `expirationMonth` and `expirationYear` fields.

If you're interested in the thought process behind this decision, check out the [github conversation](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/133#issuecomment-199373858)

Comment: It's within iframe so is it possible to do any of the following above mentioned solution?